# SwiftUI: How to customise Firebase Facebook Authentication Login button?

Tags: ios, authentication, firebase-authentication, swiftui, facebook-authentication

Im somewhat new to SwiftUI and have encountered something i cannot fix myself.

So im working with SwiftUI. And have successfully created a login page with firebase facebook authentication.

And all the functionalities work just fine, but i would like to customise the default/built-in logout button. Only the logout button if possible.
This is what i want to change it to [Its essentially just a Hstack with some text and a SF symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixFbG.png)

Would really appreciate some help

This is the code i use for authentication:

```
import SwiftUI
import FBSDKLoginKit
import Firebase


struct LoginView : UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeCoordinator() -> LoginView.Coordinator {
        return LoginView.Coordinator()
        
    }
    
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LoginView>) -> FBLoginButton {
        let button = FBLoginButton()
        button.permissions = ["email", "public_profile"]
        button.delegate = context.coordinator
        return button
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: FBLoginButton, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LoginView>) {
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator : NSObject, ObservableObject,LoginButtonDelegate{

        func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
            try! Auth.auth().signOut()
            print("Did logout")  
        }
        
        func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {
            
            if error != nil  {
                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            
            if AccessToken.current != nil {
                
                let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: AccessToken.current!.tokenString)
                Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) {(res ,  er) in

                    if er != nil{
                        print((er?.localizedDescription)!)
                        return
                    }
                    
                    print("SUCCES! ")

                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You might find you get more help if you can be specific.  What exactly to you want to change on the default button.

Comment: @PropertyWebBuilder Thanks for the reply, i have updated my initial question, so its a bit more specific. Would love for you to take a look at it, if possible

Answer (score 0):

Have you try

```
Button(action: {
      Auth.auth().signOut()
   }) {
    HStack{
        Image(systemName: "envelope.fill")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 25, height: 17)
            .foregroundColor(Color.orange.opacity(0.5))
        Text("Logout")
            .foregroundColor(Color.orange.opacity(0.5))
            .fontWeight(.medium)
            .font(.system(size: 16))
    }
}
```

Comment: Im currently calling LoginView() where the logout button should be. 
I tried using your code instead of calling LoginView() but it doesnt seem to logout the user, when clicked.
Should i use your code somewhere else? @Ernist Isabekov

Comment: hmm im not sure why doesnt logout its should logout because we calling same as func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
            try! Auth.auth().signOut()
            print("Did logout")  
        }

Comment: Just to be sure, im supposed to use your code where im calling LoginView() as the logout button, right? @Ernist Isabekov